# generate a matrix image after having all the balck pixel's coordinates with MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates

I have an Image, converted into binary, i got all the black pixel's coordinates.
The 'matrix' contains the x and y coordinates arranged by columns.
Now i Need to make a Simulation, to see if my Programme works.
I have to generate an Matrix Image with my results.

```
im=imread('square.jpg');

imshow(im); c=im2bw(im); figure; imshow(c);


dim = size(c) % size of the image
x = [];
y = [];
xdif = [];
newx = [];
matrix = [];

for i = 1:dim(1)
for j = 1:dim(2)

 if c(i,j)==0;
     x = [x i];
     y = [y j];

 end


end


end

 % show black pixel's coordinates
   p = [x;y]; 

   %number of pixels
   nr = length(x)

    dimp = size(p);

     xval = p(1,:);
     yval = p(2,:);

     j=1;
     i=1;

    for z = 1:dimp(2)-1

 xdif =  xval(z+1)-xval(z);
 ff=find(xdif > 0); 

 if ff == 1
      i = 1;
 else
     i=i+1;
 end

  newx(i,j)= xval(z);
  newy(i,j)= yval(z);


 if ff == 1
    j= j+1;

 end

end  


xsize = size(newx);
ysize = size(newy);
matrix_size = xsize(2)+ysize(2)

xinc = 1;
yinc = 1;
x=1;

for ct = 1:1:matrix_size/2

x;
matrix(:,x) = newx(:,xinc);
matrix(:,x+1) = newy(:,yinc);

matrix;

xinc = xinc+1;
yinc = yinc+1;

x=x+3;

end

matrix
```

this is my Programme, now i need to make a simulation, by generating an image with my coordinates.
how can i do that?
thank's

Comment: What kind of image are you supposed to generate? What output do you expect? binary, greyscale, photo, a transformation? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve without more details. Please your image `square.jpg` as well.

Comment: "The 'matrix' contains the x and y coordinates arranged by columns"... can you elaborate on that please? Explain further what exactly Matrix looks like and contains

Comment: ok, im giving an example:

Comment: if u open the 'matrix', u will see that on the first column are the x coordinates, the second one the y coordinates, the third are just 0 and so on... i had to make it this way, because im working with a measurement robot and my project is about painting with this robot, so, the coordinates are fine. But now, my boss, just asked me for a simulation to see how is it working... i guess it should generate the same picture, he said something like a matrix Image made by circles.

Comment: You should actually add that to your question. I don't think you will get an answer as your question is unclear. You don't define what your simulation is, for example. You have to be much more specific.

Comment: When you say "simulation", do you mean "simulate" the robot's movements give the `x,y` co-ordinates?

Comment: I'm going to suggest `scatter(x,y)` and see if that gets us anywhere.